# jQuery selectpicker refresh after adding required to select

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I just got a problem adding required via jquery to my select field.
I've tried `selectpicker('refresh')` but nothing works.

Code:

```
$('select[id*=oxStateSelect_invadr]').prop('required',true);
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are you expecting the 'refresh' to do? Generally it's used in a select library to update the `option` elements which are shown. Changing the state of the `required` attribute would have no effect...?

Comment: Why you need to add it with jQuery? You can simply add it straight to html

Comment: i can't add this to html. I have another select which updates my oxstateselect. So if i have a special option selected in my first select, i need oxstateselect as required, or not. :(

Comment: I assume that the above jQuery is actually wrapped in some event handler, can you share the event handler as well as the HTML?

Comment: Robert C which one do you mean?